# Is the comma correct? Or should it be two separate sentences or should I use a semicolon?

Tags: commas, sentence, semicolons, comma-splices

Is the comma correct in the following statement?

> Stay skeptical of news about foreign countries, especially news about countries with which we are not allied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct as written. Replacing the comma with a semi-colon would be correct, but unorthodox, and writing it as two sentences would not be grammatically correct as it lacks a verb.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jeff. It makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't see how '[r]eplacing the comma with a semi-colon would be correct' and 'writing it as two sentences would not be grammatically correct as it lacks a verb' can be possible at the same time. I'm not anti-fragment per se myself, but I've never seen the use of a semicolon before a parenthetical be licensed.

Comment: Two sentences without any changes would be stylish, actually, though not textbook. Especially to raise the stakes of the advice.